# How to play youtube video from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which a user can enter a youtube link along with their product. I want to be able to play that video (which it's link is stored in a MySQL database, the problem is that the `<iframe>` tag needs a youtube "Embed" link and not the URL, is there a way to convert the URL to the Embed link?

video_url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DIDWWKk8Bg

```
//code to connect to MySQL DB and get all rows 

$videourl = $row["video_url"];
}
?>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="<?php $videourl?>">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Whats in the database? `<?php $videourl?>` won't do anything.

Comment: Hi EKrol, your code here is a little confusing in context with your question. Are you asking how to embed video in PHP, for example? Or how to turn a URL into a YouTube embed link? The latter you may want to go to YouTube's docs for first. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular YouTube link look like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234
```

Embed YouTube link look like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/1234
```

You need just to replace this `watch?v=` to `embed/`

```
$link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234";
echo str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/",$link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use embed.

like this.

```
 $videourl = explode("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", $row['videourl']);

 <iframe class="iframeVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $videourl[1] . '"></iframe>
```

`$videourl` has to look like this `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J6o7hcm8bE`

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not use the exact url from the youtube video. The url used in iframes has the following format http://www.youtube.com/embed/unique_id_here. So you only have to save the unique_id for each video. It is only a part of the url. For example, from this url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**hdhjs88737**&list=RDEMnLv8DM0l6F9uGd8jrENGgg&index=3, the unique id is the one in bold: hdhjs88737. So here is what I would do. Go to any video on youtube and click the share option, under the options select embed. Then copy the code. It will look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<unique_id_here>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Modify the parameters in the iframe to fit your preferences then only save the unique_id to your database. That should solve your problem. Check this [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) reference for a detailed guide.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I used, I'm not sure if this code should be there twice but it works so...

```
<?php
str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/",$videourl);
?>
<iframe width="520" height="345" src="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/",$videourl);?>">
</iframe>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It should not be there twice. You first call does nothing. You need to assign or echo.